# How to avoid getUserStateFromRequest for not store in session

Tags: joomla-3.x, session, pagination

I read and understand that `getUserStateFromRequest` stores information in session.

The session storage is causing an issue on site
Is there an alternate way by which i can avoid in session storage on pagination pages

Below is code in model/list.php

```
protected function populateState($ordering = null, $direction = null)
{
    // Initialise variables.
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();

    // List state information
    $limit = $app->getUserStateFromRequest('global.list.limit', 'limit', $app->get('list_limit'));
    $this->setState('list.limit', $limit);

    $limitstart = $app->getUserStateFromRequest('limitstart', 'limitstart', 0);
    $this->setState('list.start', $limitstart);

    if ($list = $app->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context . '.list', 'list', array(), 'array'))
    {
    {
        foreach ($list as $name => $value)
        {
            // Extra validations
            switch ($name)
            {
                case 'fullordering':
                    $orderingParts = explode(' ', $value);

                    if (count($orderingParts) >= 2)
                    {
                        // Latest part will be considered the direction
                        $fullDirection = end($orderingParts);

                        if (in_array(strtoupper($fullDirection), array('ASC', 'DESC', '')))
                        {
                            $this->setState('list.direction', $fullDirection);
                        }

                        unset($orderingParts[count($orderingParts) - 1]);

                        // The rest will be the ordering
                        $fullOrdering = implode(' ', $orderingParts);

                        if (in_array($fullOrdering, $this->filter_fields))
                        {
                            $this->setState('list.ordering', $fullOrdering);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $this->setState('list.ordering', $ordering);
                        $this->setState('list.direction', $direction);
                    }
                    break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to use session storage, just directly get the values from request.

```
$limit = $app->input->getInt('limit', $app->get('list_limit'));
```

Please note that the above answer is based on assumption that the code you mentioned is from your custom component. For core component, you need to either modify the core files (not recommended) or live with it.